# What am I missing? Calculation won't show in the field

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, area

I am trying to make an area calculator and I cannot figure out what am I missing.

the area field is not updating when entering numbers in each field.

Any advice please? I wonder if I'm missing something very important.

```js
function calculateArea() {
  var form = document.getElementById("calc");
  var sLength = parseFloat(form.elements["slab_length"].value);
  var sHeight = parseFloat(form.elements["slab_width"].value);

  var slabsArea = sHeight * sLength;

  //slabsArea = Math.round(slabsArea);
  //document.getElementById("slabsArea").value = slabsArea;
  form.elements["slabsArea"].value = slabsArea;
  return slabsArea;
}
```

```html
<form id="calc">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: left;"><label>Slab Width (m): </label></th>
      <th>
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="text" name="slab_width" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onkeyup="calculateArea()" required="" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: left;"><label>Slab Length (m): </label></th>
      <th>
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="text" name="slab_length" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onkeyup="calculateArea()" required="" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: left;"><label>Total Area (m2):</label></th>
      <th>
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="text" name="slabsArea" disabled="" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: What is `calculateArea` supposed to do when one of the fields hasn't been filled in yet?

Comment: What is the purpose of `onkeypress` events? If you need only numbers, why not use `<input type="number" />`? Also, generally its cleaner to handle events in JS, using `element.addEventListener()`

Comment: I'm trying to get the area filed to update automatically as soon as the length and width fields are filled in, unless I'm doing it completely wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll simplify this for you, and you can update your HTML table as needed to format it in a way you'd like.

First, don't use `keypress`, use `keyup`. This will get the *updated* value of the input.

Next, use numeric inputs to enforce numbers. It's built in, and much easier than writing your own numeric parser. Here's sample HTML:

Third, add IDs to your elements. It makes selecting them much more efficient and easy.

Here's a sample using inputs and event listeners for brevity:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const userInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("userInput");
  for (let x=0, input; input = userInputs[x]; x++)
  {
    input.addEventListener("keyup", (evt) => { 
      let length = parseFloat(document.getElementById("slabLength").value);
      let width = parseFloat(document.getElementById("slabWidth").value);
      document.getElementById("slabArea").value = length * width;
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="slabLength" class="userInput" type="number" value="0">
<input id="slabWidth" class="userInput" type="number" value="0">
<input id="slabArea" type="number" readonly value="0">
```

Comment: I thought I've replied to your answer, thank you for your sample and explanation!

Comment: I did but it won't let me since it's my first post, they said my feedback has been registered though